# Can someone please explain class << self to me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm jumping into rails programming for the first time and while looking at the code for some libraries I've downloaded, I occasionally notice the code:

```
class << self
  def func
     stuff
  end
end
```

I've tried searching the web for an explanation, but the << gets stripped from most useful search engines, so it ends up just searching for class self, which isn't very useful.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Is google not a useful search engine? http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=class+%3C%3C+self&btnG=Google+Search

Comment: @McKay: Apart from http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/77/topics/657 , which wasn't quite the same as what Wade was doing, which hits were relevant to Wade's question?

Comment: The first two hits are both relevant (the third arguably so). The second link (http://www.thekode.net/blog/blog.html) talks about that idiom specifically and links: http://www.thekode.net/ruby/techniques/DefiningMethodsWithClosures.html which might also be of help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ruby, `class << foo` opens up the *singleton class* of the object referenced by `foo`. In Ruby, every object has a singleton class associated with it which only has a single instance. This singleton class holds object-specific behavior, i.e. singleton methods.

So, `class << self` opens up the singleton class of `self`. What exactly `self` *is*, depends on the context you are in, of course. In a module or class definition body, it is the module or class itself, for example.

If all you are using the singleton class for, is defining singleton methods, there is actually a shortcut for that: `def foo.bar`.

Here's an example of how to use singleton methods to provide some "procedures" which don't really have any association with a particular instance:

```
class << (Util = Object.new)
  def do_something(n)
    # ...
  end
end

Util.do_something(n)
```

Comment: So it's basically the way Ruby handles what would be a static method in a language like Java? Are there any differences?

Comment: @Wade - the def portion is like a static method, yes. But you can manipulate class-level variables inside the open class<<end block, and do other dynamic things in there as well. Ruby's class definitions are executed, not read statically. For instance, you can run other class level methods there, and define other classes there.

Answer (score 3):

It's the equivalent of

```
def self.func
  stuff
end
```

Except that all methods nested in it are class methods.  It allows you to declare a number of methods are class methods, without decalring each one on `self`.

Comment: True, but that's the common case.